# Debian buster: package firmware-realtek installed, rtl8192eu wifi dongle USB adapter not showing up as network interface

Tags: debian, wifi, usb-device, realtek, proprietary-drivers

I am trying to make a Wi-Fi USB adapter working, to no avail. The dongle is a TP-Link WN821N, which has a Realtek rtl8192eu chip. I cannot change it and will soon loose my wired connection due to choices of my employer.

When inserted, I get the following output from `dmesg`:

```
[12881.857485] usb 1-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[12881.970614] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0107, bcdDevice= 2.00
[12881.970617] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12881.970618] usb 1-1.6: Product: 802.11n NIC
[12881.970619] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Realtek
[12881.970620] usb 1-1.6: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

and here is the relevant output of `usb-devices`:

```
$ usb-devices|grep -C 4 Realtek
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=05 Cnt=03 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0107 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

however there's no network interface coming up

```
$ lspci -knn |grep -i net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:2008]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

also, `ip a` only shows the ethernet interface, and `iw dev` has no output.

My uninformed guess is that the system cannot find a driver for this particular dongle. I do have the non-free `firmware-realtek` package installed:

```
$ dpkg -l|grep realtek
ii  firmware-realtek                              20190114-2                              all          Binary firmware for Realtek wired/wifi/BT adapters
```

and there should be something related to `rtl8192eu` inside:

```
$ dpkg -L firmware-realtek |grep rtl8192eu
/lib/firmware/rtl_bt/rtl8192eu_fw.bin
/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_wowlan.bin

$ apt-cache show firmware-realtek|grep -i rtl8192eu
* Realtek RTL8192EU Bluetooth firmware (rtl_bt/rtl8192eu_fw.bin)
* Realtek RTl8192EU non-WoWLAN firmware (rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin)
* Realtek RTl8192EU WoWLAN firmware (rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_wowlan.bin)

$ grep -r rtl8192eu /lib/modules/4.19.0-20-amd64/
Binary file /lib/modules/4.19.0-20-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu.ko matches
```

however I do not have a module named `rtl8192eu`:

```
$ sudo modprobe rtl8192eu
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-20-amd64
```

and while I can load `rtl8xxxu` instead, it still does not make any new interface appear,
both `lspci` and `ip a` keep showing only ethernet, and `iw dev` shows nothing.

I am now faced with a hard choice: debug this, buy another dongle with my own money, or switch jobs.

- I strongly prefer a solution based on `firmware-realtek`, or another maintained package, over compiling drivers from github.
- I am willing to upgrade to Debian 11 bullseye if needed, as I was planning to do that anyway.
- I wonder if there were some installation steps where I said that I will not ever need wifi.

Can you help?

Comment: The solution proposed here works: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Availability_of_compatible_WiFi_chipsets
but it requires recompiling/reinstalling at each kernel upgrade.
It worked for me using gcc-8, no need to install gcc-6.

Answer (score 0):

After some time and a full-upgrade to Debian bullseye, I think the best available solution is to install the module from [this github repo](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver), which is more up to date than the [fork](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git) proposed on [this Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Availability_of_compatible_WiFi_chipsets) ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220727085021/https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Availability_of_compatible_WiFi_chipsets)).

Based on the instructions proposed on the repo's [readme](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver#readme), the following worked for me in Debian 11.4 bullseye, `Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-2 (2022-07-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux`:

```
sudo apt install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
```

Not sure if the last line blacklisting rtl8xxxu is needed.
After rebooting, the driver is loaded automatically:

```
$ usb-devices|grep -C 4 Realtek

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0107 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n NIC
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192eu

$ sudo iw dev
phy#0
       Interface wlxd037458b4186
               ifindex 3
               wdev 0x1
               addr d0:37:45:8b:41:86
               ssid eduroam
               type managed
               txpower 12.00 dBm
```

Under buster, I also had appended the following to
`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

following the [debian wiki guide](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi#Availability_of_compatible_WiFi_chipsets), I am not sure if it's still necessary.